# How to add to nested children of knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have some code where to add to a knockout observable array I am converting the observable array into an object, unshifting a new object and then mapping this object back to view model. This works but it seems very slow. It takes around 2-5 seconds or more.

```
function addContact(office) { // Passing in object array of agency. We no it contains correct office and agency ID

        // Assign observable data to new variable then remove old
        // variable from mapping
        var objAgency = ko.toJS(agency);

        vm.agency.removeAll();


        // Fill new object with empty strings and related data
        var objContact = {
            agencyID: office.agencyID._latestValue,
            emailAddress: "",
            firstName: "",
            jobName: "",
            office: "",
            OfficeID: office.officeID._latestValue,
            personID: "",
            surName: "",
            title: ""
        }



        // unshift where office ID match
        for (i in objAgency[0].offices) {
                if (!isNaN(i)) {
                    if (objAgency[0].offices[i].officeID === objContact.OfficeID) {
                        objAgency[0].offices[i].contacts.unshift(objContact); // At i remove one object
                    }
                else {

                }
            } 
        }
        vm.agency([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency[0])]);
    }
```

**I have tried adding to my observable instead of doing the conversion process and I got this error:**

```
Unhandled exception at line 9423, column 13 in http://localhost:13762/scripts/breeze.debug.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getProperty'
```

**This is the code that causes the error**

```
for (i in agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue) {
            if (!isNaN(i)) {
                if (agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue[i].officeID = objContact.OfficeID) {
                    agency._latestValue[0].offices._latestValue[i].contacts._latestValue.unshift([ko.mapping.fromJS(objContact)]);
                }
            }
        }
```

See my screenshot for what agency looks like:

[image: My global observable array]

What is the correct way to add to this observable array? As I understand latest value is a mechanism for tracking change so I shouldn't tamper with that?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, `._latestValue` is a property when you're referencing the knockout-{version}.debug.js file.  If you use knockout-{version}.js, that won't be there.  In any case, `myObservable._latestValue === myObservable() === ko.unwrap(myObservable)`.  You don't want to reference `_latestValue` because when you use the minified knockout js file in production, this code will break.  You should rewrite your code to:

```
for (i in agency().offices()) {
    if (!isNaN(i)) {
        if (agency().offices()[i].officeID = objContact.OfficeID) {
            agency().offices()[i].contacts().unshift([ko.mapping.fromJS(objContact)]);
        }
    }
}
```

And it's still not right because your `if` comparison isn't a comparison, it's an assignment.  Use `===`: `if (agency().offices()[i].officeID === objContact.OfficeID)`

That might do it, but I doubt it because I suspect `agency().offices()[i].officID` is also an observable, in which case you'll need to use the `()` to access its underlying value.

Another problem is that you're unshifting an array into an array, kind of like this:

```
var arr = ["A", "B"];
arr.unshift(["Z"]);
// Result: [["Z"], "A", "B"];
```

So lose the brackets inside the .unshift function, unless you're intending to add an array to your array.  Some people like to yo dawg.

And although you can call `offices().unshift(value);` and manipulate the underlying array, it's preferable that you call unshift on the observableArray directly like this: `offices.unshift(value);` because KO will then notify subscribers and update the DOM.  Otherwise, you have to inform KO that the value has mutated.  See the difference in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Jaq/).

Hopefully that will help resolve your issue.